# How to achieve block scoping in R?

Tags: r

I am thinking of ways to achieve block scoping in R. This would be nice for keeping a clean workspace in data science notebooks/interactive sessions. At the moment I am using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) pattern like so

```
(function(){
temp1 <- ...
temp2 <- ...
temp3 <- ...

data <<- fn(temp1, temp2, temp3)
})()
```

This way I can create/update data and let the temporary be cleaned up after me. Obviously it still has side-effects with regards to potentially assigning to global, but for data analysis and not software packages I'm not concerned.

Until IIFE becomes more popular in R I thought it'd be neat to have a special operator for this, but I don't know enough about R metaprogramming. In my naive head the following should have been sufficient

```
`%gets%` <- function(x, val) {
    val <- local(val)
    assign(deparse(substitute(x)), val, envir = parent.frame())
}

x1 %gets% {
    x = 10;
    x + 5
}
```

But x still get dumped out to my global scope. So

1. Is this a reasonable implementation for simulating block scoping?
2. If so, how can I prevent my x from escaping to the outside scope?

Comment: Do you mean like [`local`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html)?

Comment: I have `local` in my code, it cannot catch the expression fast enough and x escapes to the outer scope, as you will see if you run my example code. My guess is that in `val <- local(val)` the act of touching val (even inside `local`) causes it to be evaluated in the parent environment.

Comment: Few people will know *IIFE = Immediately Invoked Functional Expression*, you might as well cite [your own blog post](https://medium.com/@shiansu/iife-pattern-in-r-fcc4f42ba628), and explain succinctly how it compares to how R implements environments, e.g. the 3rd and 4th args [`assign(x, value, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos) ...)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html)

Comment: Specifically how/is IIFE different to `assign(..., new.env(parent = baseenv()) ...` , `globalenv()`, `emptyenv()` etc.? and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html ?

Comment: I've added the reference to MDN where I borrowed the pattern. The key function of IIFE is not the assignment but the cleanup of "locally" declared temporaries, so I don't know if I want to compare it to `assign()`. The motivation is to make extensive use of local variables for readability without having to worry about them polluting my overall environment. I'm sure you can equivalently do your temporary work in a explicitly declared environment but that requires a change in code structure whereas IIFE simply wraps around existing code and requires an additional `<<-` to export.

Comment: [C++](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init) guidelines on using this pattern explains the motivation whereas MDN does not. But the point of this SO question is whether a similar effect can be achieved through a special operator in R.

Comment: `<<-` doesn't necessarily assign to the global environment

Comment: @shians You’re wrong concerning `local`. It does exactly what you want. If JavaScript had `local`, it wouldn’t need IIFE.

Comment: Yes, in light of G. Grothendieck's example code I see what I should have actually done with local and how that would have accomplished my goal. It wasn't clear to me what the first comment meant and they never bothered to clarify.

Comment: @shians, *"cannot catch the expression fast enough"* makes no sense to me ... speed?? Also, *"x escapes to the outer scope"* means you aren't using `local` to its fullest. What about `data <- local({ temp1 <- ...; x <- somefunc(temp1); x})`? Nothing escapes, I have no idea what "fast enough" means, local variables do not poison the global and are typically gc'ed. (The only thing missing is the inherent ability to return two values (standard R "limitation"), which can be worked around by returning a `list`.)

Comment: @r2evans, you are right, I wasn't using `local()` properly, and how I misused it is in my example code. By fast enough I was referring to the inability to get ahead of and prevent the expression evaluating in the calling scope when used inside the function I wrote.

Comment: Oh, I see the potential for confusing R's `local(...)` with python (and other language)'s `local varname` versus `global varname`, etc. I've been using it too long to remember making that same mistake years ago. I use `local()` as an IIFE-like think in several of my R projects; I picked it up from an early version of `opencpu` source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) local** First note that this works:

```
if (exists("x")) rm(x) # just for reproducibility.  Don't need this normally.
x1 <- local({ x <- 10; x + 5})

x1
## [1] 15

x
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

**2) %gets%** To implement `%gets%` we can use `substitute` like this:

```
`%gets%` <- function(.x, .value) {
  assign(deparse(substitute(.x)), eval.parent(substitute(local(.value))), parent.frame())
}

x1 %gets% {
    x = 10;
    x + 5
}

x1
## [1] 15

x
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

**2a) :=** We can make this even nicer by defining := like this:

```
`:=` <- `%gets%`

# test
x1 := { x <- 10; x + 5}

x1
## [1] 15

x
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

**3) pipes** Also piping can be used to avoid globals.  Here `x` and `y` do not persist after the pipe completes.

```
library(magrittr)

list(x = 6) %$% { y <- 1; x + y + 5 }
## [1] 12

x
## Error: object 'x' not found

y
## Error: object 'y' not found
```

or if we have nothing to pass:

```
x1 <- list() %>% { x <- 10; x + 5 }

x1
## [1] 15

x
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

or we could use 0 to save keystrokes:

```
x1 <- 0 %>% { x <- 10; x + 5 }
```

**Update** Have revised (2) to simplify and correct it.  Also Added (2a) and (3).

Comment: `if (exists("x")) rm(x)` — I’m not sure what purpose this serves here. I’m also generally not a fan of treating the environment as a mutable workspace. Treat it as immutable as much as possible (i.e.: don’t rebind names and don’t erase them).

Comment: That is just for reproducibility of the test.  It would not otherwise be needed. When we use the subsequent code shown we would not need that statement.

Comment: Note 2a has been added.

Comment: +1 for `local`, the most R-onic method. (That doesn't sound as fluid as "pythonic", but ... is there a better way to say it? Perhaps not the best ... *"isn't it R-onic"* sounds like Alanis Morisette, and *"more R-onic"* sounds like moronic ...)

Answer (score 1):

**`local` does what you want** (and IIFE is a hack in JavaScript to work around the lack of a `local`-like functionality).

Your `%gets%` code fails because you’re misunderstanding how arguments are evaluated: in your function, `val` is an argument. This means that **it is evaluated in the caller’s scope**, no exceptions. Wrapping it in `local` simply means that the *result* of evaluating `val` is wrapped in local — i.e. meaningless in this case. It does *not* mean that the expression is evaluated locally; if that were the case, you wouldn’t need `local` at all, you could just evaluate it in the function’s scope.

You *can* do that, if you want, by using `eval`:

```
`%gets%` = function (x, expr) {
    assign(
        as.character(substitute(x)),
        eval(substitute(expr)),
        parent.frame()
    )
}
```

… but that won’t be very useful, since it cannot access variables of the caller’s scope; rather, you’d have to evaluate it in a scope that injects the caller’s scope, so that you have a “clean” environment yet can access existing variables:

```
`%gets%` = function (x, expr) {
    parent = parent.frame()
    assign(
        as.character(substitute(x)),
        eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), new.env(parent = parent)))),
        parent
    )
}
```

… but this is essentially just a convoluted way of redefining `local` assignment.